# "What questions are there?" vs. "What are the questions there?"

Tags: grammaticality, grammar, questions

Imagine this scene: "a non-native student asking another student about the questions in a paper on the table of the teacher". Which is the correct way for asking this between the two questions below:

> 1. "Hey man, what questions are there?"
> 2. "Hey man, what are the questions there?"

What are the differences between the questions 1 and 2, I mean about **meaning** and **grammar**. Are both grammatically correct? If yes, are the meanings the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both expressions are grammatical. The main difference between these two expressions is that the word *what* in "*what questions are there?*" is used as a [determiner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner), whilst in "*what are the questions there?*" it plays the role of a [pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronoun).

They basically have the same meaning. However, the determiner *the* in the expression "*what are the questions there?*" suggests that the asker knows there are questions there but is not sure what they are.

> "What are the questions there?"
>
> *expected response:*
>
> "The questions are ...."

And that is slightly different from using the determiner "*what*", which suggests that the asker has no knowledge about the subject.

> "What questions are there?"
>
> *expected response:*
>
> "The questions are ...."
>
> *or*
>
> "There are no questions."

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge,the first statement should be:

"*Hey man, which questions are there?"*.

If you want to use the word "**what**", then we can construct the statement as

*"Hey man, what type of questions are there?"*

As for the second statement, I think it is correct.